# Construção de Formulário

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Depois de vários meses sem utilizar o Laravel, agora retorno com essa versão 5. Pode parecer besteira, mas estou tendo problemas em criar um simples formulário. Pelo visto o Illumiante/html não está vindo por default no framework, então é necessário fazer algumas modificações.

Adicionei a seguintes linhas em cada arquivo:

## composer.json

```
"illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev"
```

## config/app.php

```
'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

## minha view

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@gerarPdf'))}}  
    {{ Form::text('name', 'name') }}  
    {{ Form::password('password') }}  
    {{ Form::submit('Send') }}  
{{ Form::close() }}
```

## HomeController

```
public function gerarPdf() {
    return 'ola mundo';
}
```

## Mensagem de Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## OBS

Já dei o composer update e o método já foi criado no controller.

Comment: `Laravel 5`? Ele não está na versão alpha?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Se está, eu não sei. Através do comando de instalação do Composer(fornecido pelo site do Laravel) eu obtive a 5ª versão.

Comment: A versão estável do [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) é a 5.0.6

Comment: @luciorubeens Sim, minha versão é a 5.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O projeto do antigo Html do Laravel agora é mantido pelo grupo **[Laravel Collective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)**. Atualizei alguns itens, começando pelo **composer.json**.

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Após executar `composer update` atualizei o **config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    // ...
  ],

  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
      'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    // ...
  ],
```

E a sintaxe também foi modificada.

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@gerarPdf')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('username') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale lembrar que o `illuminate/html` continua existindo como um [componente do Laravel](https://github.com/illuminate/html) e funciona perfeitamente com o Laravel 5.

Execute insira a dependência via composer:

```
composer require illuminate/html:~5.0
```

E atualize o `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
  // ...
  'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  // ...
],

'aliases' => [
  // ...
    'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
  // ...
],
```

Vale lembrar que esses pacotes não receberam atualizações no core do Laravel, podendo algumas funcionalidades pararem de funcionar.