# Atualização do Laravel via composer

Tags: laravel, composer

> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/curl.so' - /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3: symbol krb5_ntlm_init_get_challange, version HEIMDAL_KRB5_2.0 not defined in file libkrb5.so.26 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/laravel/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150

Alguém sabe porque está dando este erro, sou iniciante com o composer, alguém poderia me explicar, pois estou tentando fazer o que [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51406/laravel-5-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-formul%C3%A1rio) resposta sugere.

Comment: O curl está instalado em seu sistema? Experimente digitar no console: `curl -V` se mostrar a versão, está instalado. Se não mostrar e você estiver usando o Ubuntu ou outra distro baseada no Debian, instale com: `sudo apt-get install curl`. Depois tente denovo.

Comment: Ah, se estiver instalado, veja se o `php5-curl` está instalado olhando pela função `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Tem que ter o cURL lá. Se não tiver, `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na hora do Composer baixar as atualizações.

O Laravel inclui no arquivo do Composer alguns comandos internos para limpeza do Cache, otimização do Autoload, etc:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

Na resposta postada, faltou informar um passo importante: executar o `composer update` após alterar o arquivo `composer.json`. Como o Composer executa um comando do Laravel e em seguida você inseriu o *Service Provider* `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider`, o mesmo não existia no momento e causou o erro.

Você pode corrigir de duas formas:

1. Removendo o `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` do `config\app.php` e inserindo novamente após a atualização.
2. Atualizando o Composer sem os comandos de pré e post update: `composer update --no-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

nesse caso especifico o erro ocorreu no arquivo /var/www/laravel/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php apos eu ter executado o composer update, o erro estava na linha 150, no caso foi um erro de sintaxe, valeu por tentar ajudar.